# Can't install express JS

Tags: node.js, express

I tried to install express, but the installation failed. This is the message that the cmd returns

npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Vander\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\content-v2\sha512\81\8e
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, mkdir 'C:\Users\Vander\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\content-v2\sha512\81\8e'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Vander\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-02T23_46_13_197Z-debug.log

This is my node version:
v14.17.4

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Try to `npm cache clean --force` and then run `npm install express --save`. It solved my issue.

Comment: I tried the command and it return this

npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Vander\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\81
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, unlink 'C:\Users\Vander\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\81'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Vander\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-05T20_34_54_872Z-debug.log

Comment: Try `npm cache clean --force` if it doesn't work then manually delete C:\Users\Vander\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache folder and install npm by `npm install npm@latest -g` . You can search [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-cache/) for more details.